# cakephp sluggable behavior throwing notfoundexception

Tags: php, cakephp, slug

I'm using Aaron Pollock's sluggable behaviour in a few of my models, and it works as expected for one but when I try to view a slug in another model I get the notfoundexception being thrown.

All of the models that use the sluggable behvior are setup identically. They all have a 'slug' field in the database, they all have their models setup like this:

```
    var $actsAs = array(

    'Sluggable' => array(
        'slug_field' => 'slug',
        'slug_max_length' => 100,
        'separator' => '-'
    ),
```

And the view actions are setup like this:

```
    public function view($slug=null) {
    $this->layout='default';    
    $eventdetails = $this->Eventdetail->findBySlug($slug);
        if (!$this->Eventdetail->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('missing eventdetail'));
        }
    $this->set('eventdetails', $eventdetails);
}
```

The index action looks like this:

```
      public function index() {
    $this->Eventdetail->recursive = 0;
    $Eventdetail = $this->Eventdetail->find('all');
    debug($this->$Eventdetail);
    $this->set('eventdetails', $Eventdetail, $this->paginate());
   }
```

And when I try to debug $Eventdetail, I get the following error:

Notice (8): Array to string conversion [APP\Controller\EventdetailsController.php, line 86], which is the line debug is on.

I don't understand how sluggable works for one model and not another.

I've gone in a few circles on this, any ideas that stand out?

Cheers, Paul

Comment: debug($this->$Eventdetail); should be debug($this->Eventdetail); or debug($Eventdetail);

Comment: thanks Ayo, I overlooked that. however now that it's resolved the debug information I see is what I'd expect to see from the index view. what still remains an issue is why I get the NotFoundException, when the slug is displayed in the index view? One thing I noticed when I wrote out the problem is that the sluggable behavior does work for one model, but no others? Has anyone used the sluggable behavior for multiple models with success?